# I'm trying to change line height and font-size using css but it is not working

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to change line height and font-size using css but it is not working

HTML CODE:

```
<h2>I no longer have to sniff other dogs for love. I've found the hottest Corgi on TinDog. Woof.</h2>
```

css code:

```
h2{
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 10rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTvRM.png)

Answer (score 1):

It is working, but the font size is too big, so the text isn't visible.
Maybe make the text smaller?

```css
h2 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
```

Comment: yeah i did it because i want size of 3rem but that was not working so i changed it to 10rem to see some visible changes then i noticed both LINE_HEIGHT and FONT_SIZE property are getting cancelled, as you can see in image.